# How does T&& work?

Tags: c++, c++11

My understanding is incorrect. I thought the point of move is to force T&& instead of a T or T& overload. The signature is

> [template  typename remove_reference::type&& move (T&& arg) noexcept;](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/move/)

I also thought T&& is the same thing as T& except signifies the reference is going out of scope. From my understanding the code in the image should be safe.

rv.append would either create a new copy (which will go out of scope) or reuse rv which is going out of scope. I thought the implementation makes a copy because the move is there. Then it does append again followed by the move. When it returns I thought since its a reference to a temporary it has no idea where the temp came from and should copy it on the stack and [postpone its lifetime](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

However I am incorrect and the fix is written in there with the image. Why doesn't it work that way? Is T&& being passed by reference like I thought? What else should I know about Rvalue references?

I also don't understand how `std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique1(U&& u)` in [this example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/forward) can call two different functions

[image]

Comment: "I also don't understand how [...] in this example can call two different functions" It's also called a *universal reference*. Because of how template deduction is done, either `U` becomes an lvalue reference (if the passed argument is an lvalue) or not-a-reference (if the passed argument is an rvalue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An rvalue reference has a name, therefore it's an lvalue itself. (The idea is if you're able to refer to an object by a name, it's potentially unsafe having it implicitly moved, as it's state is mostly undefined after the move.)

```
string&& join(string&& rv, const char* ptr) {
    // rv is an lvalue here
    rv.append(", "); // modifying rv
    rv.append(ptr);  // modifying again
    return move(rv); // move required because rv is an lvalue
}
```

This returns a rvalue reference to the first argument passed. There's no copy from `rv` to the return value of `join`, as the return type is a reference and the type of that reference matches the type of the expression `move(rv)`.

The return type of `join` is an xvalue, which is an glvalue as well as an rvalue. It is therefore bound directly to the const lvalue ref `r` (no copies involved).

The temporary returned from `meow()` lasts until the end of the full-expression `const string& r = join(meow(), "purr");`. As its lifetime isn't extended, it's destroyed and `r` becomes a dangling reference.

Comment: Helpful but i'm confused. Is xvalue always a temporary value? and why ISN'T r creating room on the stack and copying it there (prolong the lifetime as i thought it would)? Also  i'm still stuck on understanding why the function calls in the example link (near the bottom) calls two different overloads

Comment: [expr]/7 has a nice note: "In general, the effect of this rule is that named rvalue references are treated as lvalues and unnamed rvalue references to objects are treated as xvalues;" (before that, it lists when an expression is an xvalue). `r` isn't creating room on the stack because you could as well have returned an rvalue reference to, say, a data member of a class (just like in the lvalue ref case). For the example at the bottom, that's related to template deduction. Maybe [this article from Scott Meyers](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) helps you.

Comment: It sounds like rvalue doesn't mean temporary. Which in case move confuses me because I thought it was meant as something like a swap but on a container known to go away. I think I understand this

Comment: @acidzombie24 Indeed. `int x; move(x)` in this example, the expression `move(x)` is an xvalue, and an xvalue is a subcategory of glvalue and rvalue (see [basic.lval]/1). Therefore, it's also an rvalue, and it doesn't refer to a temporary, but to a local (named) variable.

Comment: That article is long i'll read it when I have more time. But I did experiment with that example. I thought replacing T and U with A and int would be the exact same code http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=09305f0bb5cd309c but i get errors. What the heck is going on in the template that makes U&& accept `make_unique1(i)` while int&& does not? It seems like its no longer an int. I think I  can check the type with typeinfo but i'm too distracted atm and will try after reading that article

Comment: @acidzombie24 Basically, for the example `template<class A>void f(A&&); f(5); int x=0; f(x);` for the first call, `A` is deduced to `int` and the instantiated function is `void f<int>(int&&)`, but for the second call, `A` is deduced to `int&` and the instantiated function is `void f<int&>(int&)` (because `int& &&` is collapsed to `int&`).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37028/discussion-between-acidzombie24-and-dyp)

Comment: My head spins! Why are you saying `f<int&>` instead of `f` AFAIK `f<int&>` doesn't mean anything and is just saying `int&` is my type. Are you saying A&& can become `int&`? That sounds so very wrong but seems exactly like whats happening. That sounds like an official/standard rule.

Answer (score 4):

> rv.append would either create a new copy (which will go out of scope) or reuse rv which is going out of scope.

No, it modifies `rv` itself, there's no copying. It's a member function call that modifies `rv`.

> I thought the implementation makes a copy because the move is there.

No, when `rv.append()` is called it isn't affected by some other call that happens afterwards to the result, it just calls `std::string::append(const char*)` on `rv`.

> Then it does append again followed by the move. When it returns I thought since its a reference to a temporary it has no idea where the temp came from and should copy it on the stack and postpone its lifetime.

No, `std::move` just casts `rv` to `std::string&&`, there's no magic copying anything onto the stack.  The return value is an rvalue-reference bound to `rv`, which is an rvalue-reference bound to the temporary returned by `meow()`. Then outside the function a `const std::string&` is bound to that same temporary, then at the semi-colon the temporary goes out of scope, leaving `r` as a dangling reference.

Comment: hmm. Why doesn't `const string& r` notice it received a && and do something about the lifetime? The rest of your answer cleared many things up but i'm still stuck on understanding why the function calls in the example link (near the bottom) calls two different overloads

Comment: How does `r` "do something about the lifetime"? The language only allows references to extend lifetime when bound to a temporary, not when bound to a reference which may or may not refer to a temporary.

Comment: Maybe http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers will help you understand the example calling different functions based on forwarding of lvalues or rvalues.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, `T&&` is a reference just like `T&`, so returning an rvalue reference to a local variable is the same as returning a regular reference to a local variable, in both cases the local variable (or temporary in this case) will be destroyed when the function exits and you'll get an invalid reference. Lifetime extension does not help because a the lifetime of a temporary bound to the return value of a function is only extended until the function exits.

Returning a `string` value fixes this because the return value will be move-constructed (as a new object) from the local/temporary variable you create with `move(rv.append(", ").append(ptr))`. That way when the temporary is destroyed the object you returned will be unaffected.

One other comment, your join function should take parameter `rv` by value, not by rvalue reference (`string rv` instead of `string&& rv`). Unless the move constructor is very expensive (which it shouldn't be) the performance will be the same and you will also be able to call your function on temporary values. I can think of very few cases where you would want to declare a variable as an rvalue reference besides in a move constructor (or in template functions, but then it's really a universal reference).

Comment: "Unless the move constructor is very expensive" maybe small string optimization.

Comment: It isn't my code. It's an example given in STL talk on goingnative 2013. This makes more sense because it seems like its as legal as `string& fn() { string v("this is bad"); return v; }` which IIRC isn't legal but compiles?

Comment: @acidzombie24 that example always returns an invalid reference, while the example in your question returns an invalid reference only when `rv` is bound to a temporary (the return value from `meow()` in this case).

Comment: Make sense. Give me another minute and i'll post a related question